# storing a file in web context root

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am writing a j2ee app and at one place i m capturing image from external source and i want to store the image to the web root of my app.

I am not able to find how do it get the path for web root directory?

The defualt path if try to get is actually the jvm path not the web root.

Ther web server i m using is weblogic

I can get the ReqestContext etc but that is also the web url contenxt no the real path.

If there is any other way to store it as image then also it is fine,

Comment: Keep in mind that this will not work in clustered environments and your files may get lost after redeployment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ServletContext.getRealPath("your/path/")`.

Comment: what should i put in arguemtns of getRealPath ?

Comment: For the root folder of your Web app, you can put `"/"`.

Comment: In my case, I need to do the same but I don't have access to `ServletContext` object. My JavaBean is deployed in a Java web application and when it's invoked it appears it's running in the context of a rest API. How I can access the web root path from JavaBean?